# Reformat code style with another code style when using GitHub

Tags: github, android-studio, intellij-idea

Context : I'm working in a large project (more than 20 developpers) and we just set a "default" code style we should always apply before commit our files. The whole actual project is already updated with the "default" code style so we won't have thousand of lines that appear "modified" when we only update 2 lines of code and reformat code.

Everyone is using his own code style and when they forget to reformat code before pushing, it messes up everything.

Question : is it possible to automatically reformat code with a different code style (other than actual one) when one saves or commits or pushes files ?

We are using Android Studio and GitHub. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible as of Android Studio 1.1.

Generally speaking, everyone using their own code style is not a sustainable approach for a project. Consider that Google, a company where the number of developers is three orders of magniture larger, somehow manages to agree on a single code style for all of their projects.

Answer (score 0):

It's a terrible idea, since **automatic style formatters always mess up**, purging even intentional style violations done for extra readability. It's incredibly hard to design a formal style definition that encompasses all cases.

So it's best to agree on a **single** style and use it throughout the project.

Well, if you're still certain and you've found a command-line utility able to reformat code to your liking, you can hang it onto the Git's (not Github's) `pre-commit` hook, so that it's run for every commit attempt.